# Union of ideals is the set of non units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Not a homework problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1 and $I$,$J$ two ideals such that the set of non units is $I \cup J$ then show that either I or J is maximal.

**My failed idea**: Define the homomorphism $f: R \to R/I \oplus R/J$ as $f(r) = (r + I, r+J)$. If $I \cup J$ is not an ideal then it must not be closed under addition, that means that there is a sum $i + j = 1$ with $i \in I, j \in J$ so the homomorphism is surjective and we have the isomorphism $R/I \cap J \cong R/I \oplus R/J$.

Suppose neither $R/I$ or $R/J$ are fields then we have some non trivial ideals $N \in R/I$ and $M \in R/J$, then $M \oplus N$  is an ideal of the direct sum, so there exists some non-unit $(a,b)$ in the direct sum, let $r \in f^{-1}(a,b)$, it must be a unit, so $f^{-1} (M \oplus N)$ is the whole ring and that's the contradiction (If my argument is right).

Suppose $I \cup J$ is an ideal then it is the only maximal ideal in $R$, somehow it has to be either $I$ or $J$.... I have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a lemma.

Let $\mathscr I$ be an ideal of $R$. Suppose $\mathscr I\subset I\cup J$. Then $\mathscr I\subset I $ or $\mathscr I\subset J $.

Proof: Suppose not. Choose $x\in \mathscr I \backslash I$, $y\in \mathscr I \backslash J$. Then $x+y\in \mathscr I \backslash I \cup J$. Contradiction.

Let $\mathfrak m$ be a maximal ideal of $R$. Since $\mathfrak m$ consists only of non-units, we can safely say $\mathfrak m \subset I\cup J$ and hence by the lemma $\mathfrak m \subset I$ or $\mathfrak m \subset J$. Thus either $I$ or $J$ is maximal.

Also we have shown along the way $R$ is semi-local with at most 2 maximal ideals.

Comment: How do you know that $x+y\in\mathscr I\setminus (I\cup J)$? If for example $I=J$ and $x$ is an element which is not in this ideal then by taking $y=-x$ we definitely have that $x+y$ belongs to $I\cup J$.

Comment: @Mark: You aren't just taking something "not in the ideal". You are taking something in the ideal $\mathscr{I}$ that is not in $I$. If $I=J$, you need to take something in $\mathscr{I}\subseteq I\cup J$ that is not in $I$, and in your set-up, $\mathscr{I}\setminus I$ would be empty.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Right, I somehow forgot that $\mathscr I\subseteq I\cup J$.

Comment: @Mark hope the above comment clears your doubt. You can also check this pretty directly if you are skeptical.

Comment: @Soumik Correct, I just missed that this ideal is contained in the union. Good answer then.